# auto-enumerated multiple footnotes marginnotes tufts-style-book

Tags: footnotes, tufte, marginnote

I want to have auto-enumerated multiple footnotes (tufte-style margin notes) in a forbidden mode. At the moment I can specify the footnote number and place the notes below the itemise list but I want it inline. Can anyone help or make suggestions how to do this? MWC below:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{microtype} % Improves character and word spacing
\title{Sample: \\ Book \thanks{Thanks}} % Title of the book
\author[author]{author} % Author
\publisher{publisher} % Publisher

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item sample \footnotemark[1]
\subitem sample
\item sample\footnotemark[2]
\subitem sample
\item sample
\item sample\footnotemark[3]
\subitem sample
\item sample\footnotemark[4] 
\subitem sample
\item sample
\subitem sample
\subitem sample
\subitem sample
\subitem sample
\item sample\footnotemark[5] 
\item sample\footnotemark[6]
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\footnotetext[1]{sample}
\footnotetext[2]{sample}
\footnotetext[3]{sample}
\footnotetext[4]{sample}
\footnotetext[5]{sample}
\footnotetext[6]{sample}

\end{document}
```